# Knapsack problem with multiple groups where items belong to more than one group

Tags: optimization, combinatorics

As follow is a [Knapsack Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) where there are multiple groups and each item belongs to one group. The goal is to maximize the profits subject to the constraints. In this case, only one item from each group can be chosen with the exception of the special group.

Here is the problem : 
Maximize: $$\sum _{j=1}^{N}\sum _{j=1}^{\left | G_{i} \right |}p_{ij}x_{ij} +\sum _{j=1}^{\left | G_{s} \right |}p_{sj}x_{sj}$$
Subject to: $$
\begin{align}
(\sum _{i=1}^{n}\sum _{j=1}^{\left | G_{i} \right |}w_{ij}x_{ij} +\sum _{j=1}^{\left | G_{s} \right |}w_{sj}x_{sj})&\leq c \\
\sum _{j=1}^{\left | G_{i} \right |}x_{ij} &= 1  \\  
\sum _{j=1}^{\left | G_{s} \right |}x_{sj} &= k \\ 
x_{ij} \in \{0,1\}\\
x_{sj} \in \{0,1\}
\end{align}
$$ 
Notation: 
*N*  the number of items 
*n* the number of groups 
*c*  the capacity of a single knapsack 
*G* = {$G_{1},...,G_{n}$} the set of groups 
${\left | G_{i} \right |}$ the number of items in group $G_{i}$ 
${\left | G_{s} \right |}$ the number of items in group $G_{s}$ (special group)
$p_{ij}$  the profit of item *j* of group $G_{i}$ 
$w_{ij}$  the weight of item *j* of group $G_{i}$ 
$p_{sj}$  the profit of item *j* of group $G_{s}$ 
$w_{sj}$  the weight of item *j* of group $G_{s}$ 
*k* restraint of group $G_{s}$

This is fairly easy to solve. However, I am having trouble describing a situation where the items may be members of more than one group but can only be selected once. For example, lets say you have a fantasy sports roster. You want to optimize your selections based upon your estimated point contributions. The weights are the player's salaries. The previously provided formula will work where player to position (item to group) is in a one to one relationship. But lets say a player can fill two or more positions. The question becomes: how can this be written as a constraint in the above? Is this an entirely different problem altogether?

Comment: You could impose a constraint for any players that can occupy more than one position limiting them to at most one position.

Comment: I understand that it might make sense to write it as a constraint, but how exactly is it written?

Comment: First, how is your $x_{ij}$ defined (it's not in your list of notation)?

Comment: $x_{ij}$ is the number of item j. As you can see, this is a 0-1 problem which restricts the number of copies of each item to 1.

Comment: Then what's $i$ in $x_{ij}$?

Comment: It's the group.